# System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field

Tags: apex

I am trying to update the status field of the master record (Service Request) to close, when all the subsequent child activities status is closed.

Here is the code:

```
trigger TriggerSR_StatusUpdate on Activities__c (after update) {
  //Fetching all SR Ids in map
  List<Activities__c> SR_Ids1 = new List<Activities__c>(
    [SELECT ServiceRequest__r.id FROM Activities__c 
     where Status__c='Close' and id in :Trigger.newMap.keySet()]);

  Set<Id> SR_Ids = new Set<Id>();
  for(Activities__c act : SR_Ids1)
  {
     SR_Ids.add(act.ServiceRequest__c);
  }
  //fetching status of the activities for the corresponding Service Request
  Map<Id,ServiceRequest__c > SRMap = new Map<Id,ServiceRequest__c >(
    [SELECT id,(select Status__c from Activities__r) 
    from ServiceRequest__c where Id IN:SR_Ids]);

  List<ServiceRequest__c> SrStatus =SRMap.values();
}
```

I am getting an exception:

```
System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL 
without querying the requested field
```

What does this mean?

Comment: This isn't your question, but in case you were interested, your query isn't actually necessary.  Everything on that object is already loaded into trigger.new.  Instead of doing a query you could just loop over that and collect an Activities__c that have a status__c = 'Closed'

Answer (score 8):

You are accessing `act.ServiceRequest__c` in your for loop

```
for(Activities__c act : SR_Ids1)
{
   SR_Ids.add(act.ServiceRequest__c);
}
```

but didn't query for it first in your SOQL.

Change:

```
List<Activities__c> SR_Ids1= new List<Activities__c>([
    SELECT ServiceRequest__r.id 
    FROM Activities__c 
    where Status__c='Close' and id in :Trigger.newMap.keySet()]);
```

To include `ServiceRequest__c`.

```
List<Activities__c> SR_Ids1= new List<Activities__c>([
    SELECT ServiceRequest__r.id, ServiceRequest__c /* add that */
    FROM Activities__c 
    where Status__c='Close' and id in :Trigger.newMap.keySet()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to reproduce the exception:**

```
System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without 
querying the requested field: Opportunity.stuff__c
```

**Code:**

```
private static Opportunity reloadOpp(Opportunity opp) {
    Id oppId = opp.Id;
    return [Select Id From Opportunity Where Id = :oppId]; //stuff__c not selected here
}

static testmethod void testFoobar() {
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();        
    opp.Description = 'Carrier';
    opp.Type = 'Other';
    opp.Name = 'foobar';
    opp.StageName = 'PDP';

    try{
        insert opp;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug(Logginglevel.Error, '' + e);
    }
    Opportunity opp2 = reloadOpp(opp);
    System.assert(opp2.stuff__c.equals('foobar'));    //so the error thrown here.
}
```

When you fetch the value `opp2.stuff__c`, the compiler notices that you never pulled that value from the object returned by the method reloadOpp.  So you get the exception.